# Where are the canned comments located?

Tags: discussion, support

I am looking for a good set of canned comments for use when guiding new users around the site.  I have loaded the SE AutoReviewComments plugin for Firefox, and there are good canned responses when flagging questions or when working the review queues, but I've been trying to find the list of questions that are off-topic on SuperUser and I can't find it.

Specifically regarding [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/899566/change-aspect-ratio-169-to-43-and-zoom-in-particular-side); the user is asking for a product recommendation.  I came across it in the wild (not while working the review queues) and I know I have seen other users post a canned response for that kind of question, but I can't find where they got it from.

Is there a link to the list of questions that are specifically off-topic that I can reference for the user?  I've checked the help pages but they are very general.

Comment: the [help page](/help/on-topic) lists that recommendations are offtopic

Answer (score 2):

From a personal perspective I would have to mention that I find seeing the close reason text as both a comment and as banner actually aggravating as it is a suggestion that you believe it off topic but don't trust the community to actually close the question properly.

If you have to tell someone that their question is off topic and want a canned reason, then just make a new one that points at the on-topic page.

You are close to being able to cast real close votes and are already able to flag posts to out them into the review queue.

I would please ask you to keep those close reasons out of comments unless you regularly go through all your comments and delete ones which are posted on now closed questions.

Comment: I post it in the comments so that the user knows why I'm voting to close. The banner doesn't show until it's actually closed, and if it got closed for the same reason I voted it closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the text used if you `flag` then select `Closing` followed by `Off-Topic.

[image]

The text can be copied from this screen and added into AutoReviewComments if you so choose.

Comment: Hey @David, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We’re trying to nail down a date before Friday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?